# Trying to let on_member_update() work with my discord Bot, but it wont send a message into the channel

Tags: discord.py

I work with the rewrite version of discord.py. Here below you see my code. I have all intents enabled

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(ctx, before, after):
    channel = bot.get_channel(795648114471469077)
    if before.display_name != after.display_name:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Member update",
                              description="Nickname change",
                              colour=random.choice(bot.color_list),
                              timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    
        fields = [("Before", before.display_name, False),
                  ("After", after.display_name, False)]
                        
        for name, value, inline in fields:
            embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)
    
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code?

Comment: if i change my nickname. I dont get a message that I changed my nickname from Creyrox to Creyroxx. I dont get a error and on_message_edit & on_message_delete both work, I use there almost the same things.

Comment: try printing the `channel` variable, post the output

Comment: Nothing happen if i add print(channel) below the code and then change my name. The terminal stays the same.

Comment: Im not asking that, print the channel before getting it (in the forth line put `print(channel)`), and send the output. Also - are you getting any errors? Btw `on_message_edit` and `on_message_delete` doesn't have anything to do with your question, I don't why why you didn't even mention them

Comment: Sorry men, I thought it would help because with that 2 it do send a message to that channel

Comment: I have put print(channel) before getting it. It doesnt give a error in the terminal, it only gives a error that i use channel before getting it. If I put print(channel) right under it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now with this code.
The problem was that I hosted it from my PC and not from my raspberry pi.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    channel = bot.get_channel(795648114471469077)
    if before.display_name != after.display_name:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Member update",
                              description="Nickname change",
                              colour=random.choice(bot.color_list),
                              timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    
        fields = [("Before", before.display_name, False),
                  ("After", after.display_name, False)]
                        
        for name, value, inline in fields:
            embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)
    
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```